# Overall body fitness routine at home

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-mass, home-exercise

I am following the below routine at home in evening hours.

2 sets of 20 reps with 2 minutes break between sets.

- **squats**
- **inclined pushups**
- **hip thrust**
- **walking lunges**
- **Normal pushups**
- **crunches**

followed by 1 set each of below pushups. any number which i can do in one go with 30 seconds break.

- **Diamond pushups**
- **normal pushups**
- **wide grip pushups.**

If possible i also perform **skip rope**

I have been performing this routine for more than a month now. Should i continue the same for some more time or should i change it in any way as it doesn't seem to be adding any mass to my body.

Answer (score 1):

Doing all of these will be good for general conditioning and endurance. But for building strength and mass, not so much. That adaptation requires progress, which can take these forms:

- Increase the resistance (usually done by increasing weight lifted).
- Increase reps.
- Increase sets.
- Decrease rest times between sets.

Increasing reps is not very useful for a beginner, because once your body has adapted to performing an exercise with a given resistance for a certain number of reps, doing longer sets will lead to more adaptation in endurance.

Doing more sets isn't particularly useful either for the same reason: if a set of a certain number of reps isn't heavy enough anymore that doing multiple sets requires a lot of rest in between (say, 3 or more minutes) then it isn't going to challenge you enough to initiate an adaptation.

Limiting rest intervals between sets also targets endurance.

So that leaves us with increasing resistance, for which weight training is a necessity. A linear progression, where the weight is increased every workout while the focus is kept on sets of 5 reps, is considered optimal for a beginner.

If you don't have the possibility of doing so, I suggest to choose bodyweight exercises which can be varied in such a way that they become progressively heavier, and target sets with low repetitions, where no more than 8 can be done. Some options you have:

- Squats: find some way of loading the squat. Having dumbbells could work, or a large jug that can be filled with water and held in front of you as would be done with goblet squats. Note however that you won't be able to keep loading this to the extent that would be possible with a barbell.
- Pushups: changing the angle can work here. Putting your feet up on a surface that can be gradually increased in height would progressively make the pushups harder, but would also change the biomechanics of the movement. It would slowly move towards a motion that resembles a handstand pushup. Other options are variations in hand position (you already do these), explosive pushups (pushing yourself off the floor and doing a hand clap in between) and one-armed pushups.
- Walking lunges: if you happen to have dumbbells with weight plates, keeping these in your hands can add some weight.

Progressive overload is the basic principle for strength adaptation, without it you can't expect to gain much strength. Weighted exercises are simply the most convenient, quantifiable way of doing this. Doing bodyweight only training is always going to result in some limits, since there's no practical substitute for squats with 60+ kg on your back or deadlifts over 100 kg without equipment.

Also, don't expect to see much change in body mass in just one month. Improvements in form and neurological adaptations will contribute a lot to the initial strength gains, and even with a linear progression in weightlifting and a good caloric surplus, you shouldn't expect highly noticeable body composition results in only one month. The truth of natural bodybuilding is that it takes a substantial amount of time. Look for improvements over a longer time frame.